# Logging stdout/err from a nodejs azure web-app: Blobs still not supported?

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

- nodejs apps on azure can log stdout and stderr to the file system (d:\home\logiles\Application)
- The file system logs are automatically disabled after ~ 12 hours
- Logging to blog would be a good alternative
- According to the docs, it is still not supported for nodejs apps

Just wanted to know if that still holds true. I tried to turn ob blob logging in the portal: app => monitoring => diagnostics logs.
azure correctly creates folders (named after my app) in my blob container, but contain rather empty csv-files only.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enablediag) is right, Log to blob storage for nodejs is still not supported as of now.

As a workaround, you can take a look at [winston-azure-blob-transport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-azure-blob-transport).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, if the answer helps, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Have written a log appender for azure blob storage in the meantime. It's better anyway than to rely on stdout.

Comment: @SpaMobile, if the answer helps, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.